# Axon Server High Availability

Tags: high-availability, axon

I'm new to Axon Server. As per the development requirement, we are supposed to configure an Axon server. I was able to spin up an instance and start one with standard edition. I have following concerns.

1. How we can ensure the high availability of axon server if we have only standard edition, which is free.
2. What is their pricing model. It is for the product license or for the support subscription?
3. Clustering is available with the enterprise edition. Can we use enterprise edition in production without any licensing fee?

Answer (score 2):

Fair questions you are posing here Sajeeva.

As you have noticed, Axon Server comes in two flavors:

1. Axon Server Standard edition
2. Axon Server Enterprise edition

The former is free to use *and* the you can see the actual [implementation](https://github.com/AxonIQ/axon-server-se).

The Axon Server Enterprise edition is as you have noticed *not* free to use, as it requires an enterprise license. The enterprise edition provides additional features to make it more production feasible. Features like [clustering](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/operations-guide/setting-up-axon-server/axon-server-clustering), [multi-context](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/operations-guide/setting-up-axon-server/multi-context), dedicated [back-up or messaging nodes](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/operations-guide/setting-up-axon-server/node-roles) and [location awareness](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/operations-guide/setting-up-axon-server/tagging).

With that piece of background, we can answer you questions as follows:

> 1. How we can ensure the high availability of axon server if we have only standard edition, which is free.

The Standard edition does not provide the clustering capability of Axon Server. As such, you cannot out of the box guarantee high availability of the Axon Server instance.

> 2. What is their pricing model. It is for the product license or for the support subscription?

The pricing model is negotiable at all times. By default, it contains the Axon Server Enterprise license **plus** development and operations support. For further information on this it is suggested to [contact](https://axoniq.io/product-overview/axon-server-enterprise#modal-Axon-Server-Enterprise) AxonIQ directly.

> 3. Clustering is available with the enterprise edition. Can we use enterprise edition in production without any licensing fee?

No, you cannot, since the enterprise edition requires a license contract.

Hope this gives you the background you are looking for Sajeeva!

Comment: Thanks Steven. Could you let me know how other people use SE edition in their production setup. Is it possible to backup axon SE?

Comment: I am not 100% aware of all the specifics set up by those using the standard edition into production. First and foremost is indeed backing up the event store. For information around this, I'd suggest to read up on this section in the reference guide -> https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/operations-guide/setting-up-axon-server/backups